# Virtual NIC's in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, network-namespaces

How do I create a VNIC interface in linux?

What I want to do is create an interface that is linked in some way to a physical interface but functions in its own namespace.

I know the physical interface could be bridged; but this doesn't quite do what I want it to. I can also alias the interface but that too doesn't quite do what I want it to.

For example; in Solaris I can create a VNIC like so: `dladm create-vnic -l <phys> <vnic_name>`

Comment: How about using a dummy interface? `ip li add dummy0 type dummy` and then bridge that with the physical interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this without manual bridging (`brctl`, etc) and re-use the physical interface I went with VLANs.

Assumptions: `eth0` is the physical interface

What I did:

1. Create the VLAN interface: `ip link add link eth0 name vlan1 type vlan id 1`
2. Assign an IP to the interface: `ip addr add x.x.x.x/24 brd x.x.x.x dev vlan1`
3. Up the interface: `ip link set dev vlan1 up`

If one has a `bond` interface; the same can be applied; instead of using the `ethX` interface just use the `bond` one.